# Nested SQL Statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I haven't done too many nested statements in MySQL and I was hoping to have the below SQL looked at and let me know if there is a better/more efficient way of doing what I am trying to accomplish.

Through all of my tests it appears that everything is working properly, I just want to make sure I am meeting best practices, etc.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    -- Fab A with EMC
    -- Conditions: Anything with an EMC
    (SELECT
            count(`wo_num`)
        FROM
            `work_orders`
        WHERE
            `emc` = '1'
                AND `auth_status` = 'ACTIVE') as `a_count_e`,
    -- Fab A Without EMC
    -- Conditions: NO EMC, Contract price greater than 10,000, NOT "Time and Material", NOT Service Order, NOT Contract Install
    (SELECT
            count(`wo_num`)
        FROM
            `work_orders`
        WHERE
            `emc` = '0'
                AND replace(replace(`contract_price`, ',', ''), '$', '') >= 10000
                AND `auth_status` = 'ACTIVE'
                AND `contract_install` = '0'
                AND `terms` <> 'TIME AND MATERIAL'
                AND `wo_type` <> 'SERVICE ORDER') as `a_count`,
    -- Fab B
    -- Conditions: NO EMC, Contract price between 1500 and 9999, NOT "Time and Material", NOT Service Order, NOT Contract Install
    (SELECT
            count(`wo_num`)
        FROM
            `work_orders`
        WHERE
            `emc` = '0'
                AND replace(replace(`contract_price`, ',', ''), '$', '') >= 1500
                AND replace(replace(`contract_price`, ',', ''), '$', '') <= 9999
                AND `auth_status` = 'ACTIVE'
                AND `contract_install` = '0'
                AND `terms` <> 'TIME AND MATERIAL'
                AND `wo_type` <> 'SERVICE ORDER') as `b_count`,
    -- Small
    -- Conditions: NO EMC, Contract price between 600 and 1499, NOT "Time and Material", NOT Service Order, NOT Contract Install
    (SELECT
            count(`wo_num`)
        FROM
            `work_orders`
        WHERE
            `emc` = '0' AND `auth_status` = 'ACTIVE'
                AND `wo_type` <> 'SERVICE ORDER'
                AND `contract_install` = '0'
                AND `terms` <> 'TIME AND MATERIAL'
                AND replace(replace(`contract_price`, ',', ''), '$', '') >= 600
                AND replace(replace(`contract_price`, ',', ''), '$', '') <= 1499) as `sm`,
    -- XX
    -- Conditions: NO EMC, Contract price less than 600, NOT "Time and Material", NOT Service Order, NOT Contract Install
    (SELECT
            count(`wo_num`)
        FROM
            `work_orders`
        WHERE
            `emc` = '0' AND `auth_status` = 'ACTIVE'
                AND `wo_type` <> 'SERVICE ORDER'
                AND `contract_install` = '0'
                AND `terms` <> 'TIME AND MATERIAL'
                AND replace(replace(`contract_price`, ',', ''), '$', '') <= 599) as `xx`,
    -- TM
    -- Conditions: NO EMC, NOT Service Order, NOT Contract Install
    (SELECT
            count(`wo_num`)
        FROM
            `work_orders`
        WHERE
            `emc` = '0'
                AND `auth_status` = 'ACTIVE'
                AND `contract_install` = '0'
                AND `wo_type` <> 'SERVICE ORDER'
                AND `terms` = 'TIME AND MATERIAL') as `tm`,
    -- Contract Install
    -- Conditions: NO EMC, IS Contract Install
    (SELECT
            count(`wo_num`)
        FROM
            `work_orders`
        WHERE
            `emc` = '0'
                AND `auth_status` = 'ACTIVE'
                AND `contract_install` = '1') as `ci`,
    -- Service
    -- All NO EMC, IS Service Order, NOT Contract Install
    (SELECT
            count(`wo_num`)
        FROM
            `work_orders`
        WHERE
            `emc` = '0'
                AND `wo_type` = 'SERVICE ORDER'
                AND `auth_status` = 'ACTIVE'
                AND `contract_install` = '0') as `service`,
    -- Total count
    -- All Active orders
    (SELECT
            count(`wo_num`)
        FROM
            `work_orders`
        WHERE
            `auth_status` = 'ACTIVE') as `total`
FROM
    `work_orders`
WHERE
    `auth_status` = 'ACTIVE'
```

Results:

[image]

---

**Side Note:**

Forgive me for the

```sql
`replace(replace(`contract_price`, ',', ''), '$', '')`
```

When the application was originally written the contract prices were stored as dollar amounts with `$` and `,`, so I have to remove them for numerical comparisons.

Comment: Do you need 1 row that is returned or multiple rows may also?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first thing to comment on, requires bold (sorry for shouting....) ***store numbers as numbers, not strings!!!***

@Malachi is right that `replace(replace(contract_price, ',', ''), '$', '')` is inefficient, and should not be repeated, but it would be even better for it to not exist at all.... your `contract_price` column should be an integer, or decimal value if you have cents.

If you **do** have cents, then you should know that you may be missing values. The statements like:

> ```
> AND replace(replace(`contract_price`, ',', ''), '$', '') >= 600
> ```

Will convert [both sides of the comparison to floating-point values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/type-conversion.html), and, there may be values with `contract_price` of `$599.50` ... right, and that will not be `>= 600`. We expect `$599.50` to fall in to the bucket below that, but that bucket has the condition:

> ```
> AND replace(replace(`contract_price`, ',', ''), '$', '') <= 599
> ```

and `$599.50` is not `<= 599`....

To get the comparisons right, you need to compare to `< 600`. THat way, you won't have gaps in your buckets.

Then, the select statement you are running is very inefficient. You can reduce it to a single query, with conditional values in the select. Consider the following:

```
SELECT

    -- Fab A with EMC
    -- Conditions: Anything with an EMC
    SUM(case when `emc` = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as `a_count_e`,

    -- Fab A Without EMC
    -- Conditions: NO EMC, Contract price greater than 10,000, NOT "Time and Material", NOT Service Order, NOT Contract Install
    SUM(case when `emc` = '0'
                AND `contract_price` >= 10000
                AND `contract_install` = '0'
                AND `terms` <> 'TIME AND MATERIAL'
                AND `wo_type` <> 'SERVICE ORDER'
        then 1 else 0 end) as `a_count`,

    -- Fab B
    -- Conditions: NO EMC, Contract price between 1500 and 9999, NOT "Time and Material", NOT Service Order, NOT Contract Install
    SUM(case when `emc` = '0'
                AND `contract_price` >= 1500
                AND `contract_price` < 10000
                AND `contract_install` = '0'
                AND `terms` <> 'TIME AND MATERIAL'
                AND `wo_type` <> 'SERVICE ORDER'
        then 1 else 0 end) as `b_count`,

    -- Small
    -- Conditions: NO EMC, Contract price between 600 and 1499, NOT "Time and Material", NOT Service Order, NOT Contract Install
    SUM(case when `emc` = '0'
                AND `contract_price` >= 600
                AND `contract_price` < 1500
                AND `contract_install` = '0'
                AND `terms` <> 'TIME AND MATERIAL'
                AND `wo_type` <> 'SERVICE ORDER'
        then 1 else 0 end) as `sm`,

    -- XX
    -- Conditions: NO EMC, Contract price less than 600, NOT "Time and Material", NOT Service Order, NOT Contract Install
    SUM(case when `emc` = '0'
                AND `contract_price` < 600
                AND `contract_install` = '0'
                AND `terms` <> 'TIME AND MATERIAL'
                AND `wo_type` <> 'SERVICE ORDER'
        then 1 else 0 end) as `xx`,

    -- TM
    -- Conditions: NO EMC, NOT Service Order, NOT Contract Install
    SUM(case when `emc` = '0'
                AND `contract_install` = '0'
                AND `terms` = 'TIME AND MATERIAL'
                AND `wo_type` <> 'SERVICE ORDER'
        then 1 else 0 end) as `tm`,

    -- Contract Install
    -- Conditions: NO EMC, IS Contract Install
    SUM(case when `emc` = '0'
                AND `contract_install` = '1'
        then 1 else 0 end) as `ci`,

    -- Service
    -- All NO EMC, IS Service Order, NOT Contract Install
    SUM(case when `emc` = '0'
                AND `wo_type` = 'SERVICE ORDER'
                AND `contract_install` = '0'
        then 1 else 0 end) as `service`,

    -- Total count
    -- All Active orders
    COUNT(*) as `total`
FROM (select Cast(replace(replace(`contract_price`, ',', ''), '$', ''), Decimal(10,2)) as `contract_price`,
             `emc`,
             `contract_install`,
             `wo_type`,
             `terms`
        from `work_orders`
        WHERE `auth_status` = 'ACTIVE')
```

Since changing trhe data type in the column is not feasible, the above query has been edited to do the conversion in just one pace...

Here's the from/where clause if the table had numeric `contract_price`....
(Replace the original from and where clause )

```
FROM
    `work_orders`
WHERE
    `auth_status` = 'ACTIVE'
```

Comment: I am VERY aware of never storing numerical values as Strings, inheriting projects is not always friendly. I would love to run a quick little script to turn every entry's contract price into a numerical value but I am not being given the time to work on this project in order to make sure the front end shows it properly and remove and server side concoction the other dev may or may not have used

Comment: @Asok, What data type is `contract_price` ?  looks like you can change the column type without losing data.  you just have to make sure that you don't have any null values hiding in there

Comment: Need to remove all instances of `CASE` after `END`, otherwise it throws a `1064` - `..MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'case) as a_count_e,..`. I ran your version (with contract price as a string still) vs my/Malachi's nested SQL on the full data pool (not restricting to active orders) in MySQL workbench and it resulted in 0.109 vs 0.110 duration, maybe my data set isn't large enough to see a difference or I am not properly bench-marking? 9000 records.

Comment: @malachi Unfortunately `contract_price` is stored as a `varchar(100)` with dollar signs and commas, I can't change it at this point.

Comment: @Asok - I have updated the query... two things: fixed the `end case` (I think), and changed the from-clause to be a subselect which does just one cast-to-decimal for the `contract-price`

Comment: writing a query to move the data into another table, then changing it to the right format and then moving it back, wouldn't take all that much time, especially for a table of only 9k records.   you should do it now, before the table gets too big.  create a new table to test the process, then remove the symbols from the column for all records and then convert to int (or float)

Comment: @rolfl With a couple minor changes to your modified code it is executing at a faster rate. Thanks. *Changes:* create an alias for the `FROM (SELECT)` I just used `cp_tbl` to tie me over. ALso `CAST()` does not take commas, should use `AS` instead `.. AS Decimal(10,2))`

Comment: @malachi Changing the table would take minutes for me. The problem is that the previous programmer hated OOP and has `contract_price` values manipulated, displayed and everything else you can think of in a ton of different places. Luckily I did convince my boss to let me re-write a good chunk of it but I have to finish this reporting project and a couple others first. I will get around to it, trust me. I am OCD about consistency and best practices, which is partly why I posted this question.

Comment: @Asok Feel free to edit the answer if I have made mistakes. I have used so many different databases in the past that I have all the subtle syntax differences mixed up, and I don't have the working/populated system here to test it on. I often use [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/) when the problems are manageable.

Answer (score 3):

Get rid of your Commented Code it's messy

---

This bit of Code might be shortened

```
AND replace(replace(`contract_price`, ',', ''), '$', '') >= 1500
AND replace(replace(`contract_price`, ',', ''), '$', '') <= 9999
```

to something like this, <strike>(*if it works the way I think it should*)</strike>  <sub>it does work like I think it should.</sub>

```
AND REPLACE(REPLACE(`contract_price, ',',''),'$','') BETWEEN 1499 AND 10000 --(or 1500 AND 9999)
```

I know this works with Dates in SQL Server but I haven't really tried it in MySQL as I don't play with it much.

this would help performance in that you would only have to run the `REPLACE` function twice here instead of 4 times

### EDIT:

my logic is a little flawed.  the end points are semi ambiguous,

the statement should be something like the following:

```
AND REPLACE(REPLACE(`contract_price, ',',''),'$','') BETWEEN 1500 AND 9999
```

and if you aren't holding Cents for this specific operation then:

```
AND REPLACE(REPLACE(`contract_price, ',',''),'$','') BETWEEN 1501 AND 9999
```

---

And the previous one would look like this

```
AND REPLACE(REPLACE(`contract_price, ',',''),'$','') BETWEEN 600 AND 1499.99
```

OR with out the Cents:

```
AND REPLACE(REPLACE(`contract_price, ',',''),'$','') BETWEEN 600 AND 1499
```

---

Where do you define column `auth_status`,  you use it in the `WHERE` clause of the outside `SELECT` statement but it doesn't exist as a column in the outer table that is built?

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. Comments are not in my actual code, they are there to break apart the SQL in the OP to (what I had hoped) read easier.

Comment: Regarding `auth_status`, that is a good question, that is a column in the `work_orders` table, this entire SQL statement is pulling from the single table. I don't know if I need that since it is in the inner sql statements?

Comment: doing a `WHERE` when you don't need to can occasionally have adverse side-effects to the performance of the query.

Comment: This is great information, thank you. I removed the external `WHERE` and it works great. I am going to try your suggestions on the `contract_price` comparison. Thanks again. Marking as accepted. Any other suggestions is greatly appreciated.